# Custom PHP hook on order details in Prestashop 1.5

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I want to run some of my own custom PHP code on the order details when the order confirmation page shows to the user in a Prestashop 1.5.5.0 - after he has returned from payment. It has to work on all types of payment, also pay-in-store options. On every order confirmation page.

Can anybody show me a simple script/method for that? Or maybe a good link?

Answer (score 6):

You can use prestashop hook displayOrderConfirmation, which should be common to all payment methods. Just create a new function in your module

```
public function hookDisplayOrderConfirmation($params) {
   //do whatever
}
```

and in module installation register this hook using `$this->registerHook('displayOrderConfirmation');`, which `$params` are passed to this function can be found at `/controllers/front/OrderConfirmationController#displayOrderConfirmation()`.

Comment: Worked for me on PS1.6 , bankwire, paypal (2015)

Comment: not working for COD, is there any another function for COD ? @klimpond

Comment: This is supposed to work on any module. Hooks are Prestashop's quite reliable feature. Can you provide more details or create a new question?